HttpClient behaving differently in .NET Framework 4.8.1 and .NET Core 8 for some APIs
I have a rest API, upon executing that API using HttpClient, it is behaving differently in .NET framework 4.8.1 and .NET Core 8.
The behavior of .NET Core is correct and it matches with Postman.

Postman - API Working as expected
HttpClient on .Net Core - API
Working as expected
HttpClient on .Net Framework - API Working only
when I set the HttpVerson to 1.0

Screenshot of Postman:

.NET Framework code when no HttpVersion is set explicitly:
    Dim client = New HttpClient()
    Dim request = New HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://api_endpint:port/b1s/v2/Login")
    Dim content = New StringContent("{ ""CompanyDB"": ""XXXX"", ""UserName"": ""XXXX"", ""Password"": ""XXXX"" }", Nothing, "application/json")
    request.Content = content
    Dim ff = request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result
    Dim response = client.SendAsync(request).Result
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()

.NET Framework code output when no HttpVersion is set explicitly:
StatusCode: 500, ReasonPhrase: 'Internal Server Error', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
    Connection: close
    Date: Wed, 13 Nov 2024 05:20:37 GMT
    Set-Cookie: ROUTEID=.node2; path=/;Secure;SameSite=None
    Server: Apache/2.4.51
    Server: (Unix)
    Content-Length: 0
}

.NET Framework code when HttpVersion is set to 1.0:
    Dim client = New HttpClient()
    Dim request = New HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://api_endpint:port/b1s/v2/Login")
    request.Version = HttpVersion.Version10
    Dim content = New StringContent("{ ""CompanyDB"": ""XXXX"", ""UserName"": ""XXXX"", ""Password"": ""XXXX"" }", Nothing, "application/json")
    request.Content = content
    Dim ff = request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result
    Dim response = client.SendAsync(request).Result
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()

.NET Framework code output when HttpVersion is set to 1.0:
StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
    Vary: Accept-Encoding
    Date: Wed, 13 Nov 2024 05:27:46 GMT
    Set-Cookie: B1SESSION=<token>;HttpOnly;;Secure;SameSite=None
    Set-Cookie: ROUTEID=.node2; path=/;Secure;SameSite=None
    Server: Apache/2.4.51
    Server: (Unix)
    Connection: close
    Content-Type: application/json; odata.metadata=minimal; charset=utf-8
}

.NET Core code:
    Dim client = New HttpClient()
    Dim request = New HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://api_endpint:port/b1s/v2/Login")
    Dim content = New StringContent("{ ""CompanyDB"": ""XXXX"", ""UserName"": ""XXXX"", ""Password"": ""XXXX"" }", Nothing, "application/json")
    request.Content = content
    Dim ff = request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result
    Dim response = client.SendAsync(request).Result
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()

.NET Core output:
StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
      Vary: Accept-Encoding
      Date: Wed, 13 Nov 2024 05:27:46 GMT
      Set-Cookie: B1SESSION=<token>;HttpOnly;;Secure;SameSite=None
      Set-Cookie: ROUTEID=.node2; path=/;Secure;SameSite=None
      Server: Apache/2.4.51
      Server: (Unix)
      Connection: close
      Content-Type: application/json; odata.metadata=minimal; charset=utf-8
}


Sorry, but exactly is your question?

Is your request made against an endpoint where you could see the webserver logs?

This looks like an issue with the server not the client, but you haven't shown the server code at all. On a side note: .Result don't ever use this, use Await instead. You also need to dispose a bunch of objects with Using.

@Charlieface, I actually do not have access to the server code.. Also if this is a server isssue it shouldn't have worked with Postman.
Regarding await and result thing.. I just did a small POC so used Result instead of await

@PeterCsala, the issue is that same api works flawlessly on postman and using HttpClient on .net core client but have issues with .net frameworkd based httpclient. The webserver is out of my access so can't see the webserver logs

And have you checked what header Postman is sending? I suggest you use a transparent proxy such as Fiddler to see what headers are actually being sent by different clients.

@raunakchoraria .NET 8 is .NET Core 8, a completely different platform. The HttpClient class for .NET Framework was last released in 2018. After 6 years and huge changes in .NET Core, differences are expected. Using .Result is begging for trouble though. HttpClient is natively asynchronous. I don't remember what quirks it had 6 years ago, but it did have some.

odata.metadata? Are you calling an OData endpoint?
